# ugly beam profile in noncollinear optical parametric amplifier

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, non-linear-optics

I am currently (re)building a noncollinear optical parametric amplifier (NOPA). Such NOPA is seeded with supercontinuum white light (SWL), generated in a sapphire window, by ~100 fs, 795 nm centred pulses from a 1 KHz Ti:Sapph chirped pulse amplifier (CPA). The NOPA pump is just the doubled fundamental of the CPA. Type I phase matching in BBO, a pretty standard system...

Now, timing and overlap seem to be ok because I can get a tunable NOPA output which is ~20-25% of the pump power.

What is confusing me is that, rather then a 2D gaussian, the amplified beam looks more like an arc of the superfluorescence ring I observe when the SWL is blocked. Furthermore, the amplified arc-shaped signal displays interference patters.

Anyone had the same issue before/suggestions on how to improve the NOPA beam profile?

Comment: Are you sure the conditions of the seed did not change? Especially spatially? Did you try to re-image the amplification spot? Moving the crystal changes anything?